Can not connect to sql server on Azure Pipeline using TestContainers
I been adding a integration test using Testcontainers
Building my container like this in my IntegrationTestFactory.cs
private readonly MsSqlContainer _dbContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
        .Build();

Was a bit surprise how easy it would work locally but when pushing it into Azure Pipeline it fails with this error
Error Message:
   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
---- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Resource temporarily unavailable

also tried adding this
.WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest")

But still fails.
My log says :
[testcontainers.org 00:00:04.06] Execute "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -Q SELECT 1;" at Docker container e7255388023f
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: / Available 18225.00 MB out of 74244.00 MB, Memory: Used 2097.00 MB out of 6921.00 MB, CPU: Usage 5.18%
[testcontainers.org 00:00:10.27] Docker container e7255388023f ready

So it looks to me like the contianer is all good
What did I miss?
pipeline
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-22.04'

variables:
  system.debug: true
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore NuGet packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    
- script: |
    echo "Checking Docker installation..."
    docker --version
  displayName: 'Check Docker Installation'

- script: |
    echo "Pulling SQL Server Docker image..."
    docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
  displayName: 'Pull SQL Server Docker Image'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: 'tests/*/*.csproj'
    publishTestResults: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura'

# First install the tool on the machine, then run it
- script: |
    dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
    reportgenerator -reports:$(Agent.WorkFolder)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CodeCoverage -reporttypes:'HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura'
  displayName: Create code coverage report

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura'
    summaryFileLocation: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
    reportDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage/'
    additionalCodeCoverageFiles: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.json'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish projects'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
    PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)


Can you provide the detailed YAML of your pipeline to test the MSSQL with Testcontainers?

Added azure-pipeline

Try the following command to run the test: docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock.raw:/var/run/docker.sock mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest dotnet test

Locally or add it to the pipeline ?

When you run the command to start the tests. Currently, you are using the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to run the 'dotnet test' command in your pipeline. You can try to change to use a Bash@3 task to run above command to start the tests in your pipeline. @Jepzen

get this error then
##[error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s'.
The test project using TestContianer is also having some test not using the TestContianer btw

All right. After the step to pull the docker image, try to add a Bash@3 task to execute the command "docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock.raw:/var/run/docker.sock mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest" to start the docker container, then use the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task to run the 'dotnet test' command. @Jepzen

Get the same error
##[error]Invalid file path '/home/vsts/work/1/s'.

You mentioned the test can work fine when you manually run it on your local machine. you can try to set up a self-hosted agent on the local machine to run the pipeline. When configure the self-hosted agent, set the the agent to logon the machine with the account and password that you are using to logon the machine. Then run the same command lines as that when you manually run the test on local.
